# Remote: true with link_to with params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have following problem

I have link_to

```
//_sort_by.html.erb
 <%= link_to "sort", :sort_by => "things", remote: true %>
```

And in my controller I have function which choose posts according to sort_by

```
def show_posts    
    @category=Category.find_by(name: params[:sort_by])

    if(@category)

    @posts=Post.where(category_id: @category)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js  
      format.html
    end

    else
      @posts=Post.all
    end
 end
```

and in views

```
   //show_posts.html.erb
       <div class="posts">
                      <%= render @posts %> 
       </div>
   // 
   and I have _post.html.erb
```

It works fine (obviously without remote: true), but it refreshes site everytime when I change category of posts so
in show_posts.js.erb I'd like to refresh only class="posts", like

```
  $('.posts').load(location.href + " .posts");
```

In routes.rb I have get 'show_posts'. But unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Could someone help me?

Edit:
 changing show_posts.js.erb to

```
  $('.posts').html("<%= j render @posts %>");
```

works. Thank you all for tips!

Comment: can you tell us what error is coming?

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't change list of posts according to selected category

Comment: do you have partial of posts?

Comment: You will have to replace the content of 'posts' class with new content something like this
$('.posts').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'post') %>")

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('.posts').append("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'posts') %>");
```

Change your show_posts.js.erb with these contents.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
$('.posts').html("<%= j render 'post' %>");
```

Hope this helps!